# How to solve an ODE system that periodically increases in size

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, ecology

I have an ODE system that increases in size according to the rules

```
n = 5;
T = 50;
nu = 0.05;
vars = Table[Subscript[x, j][t], {i, n}, {j, i}];
eqns = Table[{Subscript[x, j]'[t] == 
    Subscript[x, j][
      t] (1 - Subscript[x, j][t] - 
       nu (Sum[ Subscript[x, k][t] Boole[k != j], {k, i}]) ), 
   Subscript[x, j][0] == 
    If[j == 1 && i == 1, 0.7, 
     If[j == i, 
      0.01 Subscript[x, RandomInteger[{1, j - 1}]][t] /. t -> T, 
      Subscript[x, j][t] /. t -> T]]}, {i, n}, {j, i}]
```

I want solve the differential equation of n variables, with initial conditions defined using the previous differential equation solution of n-1 variables and with an initial condition for the last variable (which randomly depends on one of the previous variables).

I'm having trouble building the initial conditions, present in the code above

```
 Subscript[x, j][0] == 
        If[j == 1 && i == 1, 0.7, 
         If[j == i, 
          0.01 Subscript[x, RandomInteger[{1, j - 1}]][t] /. t -> T, 
          Subscript[x, j][t] /. t -> T]]
```

Where the first initial condition `{x1[0]=0.7}`

The next `{x1[0]=x1[Last time in j past],x2[0]=[Last time in j past]}`

.
.
.

```
{{x1[0]=[Last time in j past],x2[0]=x2[Last time in j past],x3[0]==x3[Last time in j past],x4[0]=x4[Last time in j past],x5=0.01xSubscript[RandomInteger[1,j-1]][Last time in j past]}
```

can anybody help me?

Comment: I'm sorry but your question is unclear.  What does it mean "ODE system that increases in size according to the rules"? and "This code solve the system of according with interpolation structure {{x1},{x1,x2},{x1,x2,x3},{x1,x2,x3,x4,},{x1,x2,x3,x4,x5}}"?  Could you explain what problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: To solve the above system

`n = 5;
T = 50;
nu = 0.05;
vars = Table[Subscript[x, j][t], {i, n}, {j, i}];
eqns = Table[{Subscript[x, j]'[t] == 
    Subscript[x, j][
      t] (1 - Subscript[x, j][t] - 
       nu (Sum[ Subscript[x, k][t] Boole[k != j], {k, i}]) ), 
   Subscript[x, j][0] == 
    If[j == 1 && i == 1, 0.7, 
     If[j == i, 
      0.01 Subscript[x, RandomInteger[{1, j - 1}]][t] /. t -> T, 
      Subscript[x, j][t] /. t -> T]]}, {i, n}, {j, i}]
sol0 = Table[s = NDSolve[eqns[[l]], vars[[l]], {t, 0, T}], {l, n}]`

I forgot to add the NDSOlve part

Comment: @ChrisK The result of interpolation NDSolve provides the results of the form {{x1},{x1,x2},{x1,x2,x3},{x1,x2,x3,x4,},{x1,x2,x3,x4,x5}}. The initial conditions  follows the same structure. I need to give the initial condition for each j by taking into account the last value given to j previous. For example, for `j=1 Subscript [x, 1] [0] = 0.7`. For `j = 2`, the initial conditions `Subscript [x, 1] [0] = Subscript [x, 1] [T], Subscript [x, 2] [0]= Subscript [x, 1] [T] `, Where `Subscript [x, 1] [T]` is the last value of the interpolation obtained at `j = 1`.

Comment: I think verbally describing the problem you want to solve will be clearer than using Mathematica code.

Comment: If you share the mathematical form of the problem then it might help?

Comment: @ChrisK I edited this question

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a Lotka-Volterra competition model with weak, symmetric interspecific competition.  If I understand correctly, you want to build up a community by introducing new species every `T=50` time steps, where the new species has initial density of 0.01 times one of the existing species.

Call me old-fashioned, but I think this is easiest to understand when handled in an iterative `Do` loop:

```
nmax = 5; (* max number of species *)
T = 50; (* period *)
nu = 0.05; (* interspecific competition coefficient *)

(* set up unknown vars and differential equations, for n species *)

vars := Table[Subscript[x, j], {j, n}];
eqns := Table[Subscript[x, j]'[t] == Subscript[x, j][t]
  (1 - Subscript[x, j][t]- nu (Sum[Subscript[x, k][t] Boole[k != j], {k, n}]))
, {j, n}];

(* initial ICs *)
ics = {Subscript[x, 1][0] == 0.7};

(* main loop *)
Do[
  (* solve for n species *)
  sol[n] = NDSolve[{eqns, ics}, vars, {t, 0, T}][[1]];
  (* plot dynamics *)
  Print[Plot[Evaluate[Table[Subscript[x, j][t], {j, n}] /. sol[n]], {t, 0, T}, PlotRange -> {0, All}]];

  (* set up ICs for n=n+1 species *)
  ics = Join[
    Table[Subscript[x, j][0] == Evaluate[Subscript[x, j][T] /. sol[n]], {j, n}],
    {Subscript[x, n + 1][0] == Evaluate[0.01 Subscript[x, RandomInteger[{1, n}]][T] /. sol[n]]}
   ];
, {n, nmax}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

Not sure how interesting this is, since I believe this symmetric LV system has a globally stable equilibrium at $x_i=1/(1-(n-1)nu)$ as long as $0<nu<1$, but you could use this as a basis for more interesting explorations of community assembly.

**Edit**

Here's a 3D phase portrait of the first three periods for @MMM:

```
Show[
  ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[{Subscript[x, 1][t], 0, 0} /. sol[1]], {t, 0, T}],
  ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[{Subscript[x, 1][t], Subscript[x, 2][t], 0} /. sol[2]], {t, 0, T}],
  ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[{Subscript[x, 1][t], Subscript[x, 2][t], Subscript[x, 3][t]} /. sol[3]], {t, 0, T}],
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If possible, please include a phase portrait?

Comment: @MMM The dimension of the system keeps increasing, so that'd be tough without `ParametricPlot5D`! :) :)

Comment: As a test case, restrict it to 3 species or even 2.

Comment: @MMM OK see edit above

Comment: I did. Thankyou

Comment: @ChrisK If the parameter `nu = 0.05` is replaced by a random variable `nu = RandomReal []`, could you, please, tell me how to do `1000` processes to generate statistics? I tried to use `Table` and `Do` but I did not succeed.  Thank you so much.

Comment: @SAC That sounds like it deserves a separate question, if you want to close this one & ask another one showing what you've done.  BTW, when you say a random variable `nu`, is that one `nu` for everyone, a species-specific `nu`, or an interaction-specific `nu`?

Comment: @ChrisK The random variable `nu` would be replaced as: `nu = 0.05;` by `nu[j_,k_]:=RandomReal[]` and `eqns := Table[Subscript[x, j]'[t] == Subscript[x, j][t]
  (1 - Subscript[x, j][t]- (Sum[nu[j,k] Subscript[x, k][t] Boole[k != j], {k, n}]))
, {j, n}];`. I try to solve 1000 operations instead of 1,  the same way as you solved this post.

Comment: I thought about changing the way `Do[
  (* solve for n species *)
  sol[n] = NDSolve[{eqns, ics}, vars, {t, 0, T}][[1]];
   (* set up ICs for n=n+1 species *)
  ics = Join[
    Table[Subscript[x, j][0] == Evaluate[Subscript[x, j][T] /. sol[n]], {j, n}],
    {Subscript[x, n + 1][0] == Evaluate[0.01 Subscript[x, RandomInteger[{1, n}]][T] /. sol[n]]}
   ];
, {n, nmax},{q,1000}]` but this is not right.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly, I think the following is what you want:

Solve the differential equation of `n` variables, with initial conditions defined using the previous differential equation solution of `n-1` variables and with an initial condition for the last variable (which randomly depends on one of the previous variables).

The following code uses `iniCond` which generates initial conditions for a given `i`, `diffGen` generates equations with the initial conditions, and finally `solveDiffGen` solves the differential equations.

```
T = 50;
nu = 0.05;
vars[i_] := Subscript[x, #][t] & /@ Range[i];
iniCond[1] = {Subscript[x, 1][0] == 0.7};
diffGen[i_] := 
  Join[Table[{Subscript[x, j]'[t] == 
       Subscript[x, j][
         t] (1 - Subscript[x, j][t] - 
          nu (Sum[Subscript[x, k][t] Boole[k != j], {k, i}]))}, {j, 
      i}], iniCond[i]] // Flatten;
iniCond[i_] := 
  Module[{prevSolConds, lastCond}, 
   prevSolConds = 
    NDSolve[diffGen[i - 1], 
       vars[i - 1], {t, 0, 
        T}] /. (x_ -> g_) :> {(x /. {t -> 0}) == (g /. {t -> T})} // 
     Flatten;
   lastCond = 
    Subscript[x, i][0] == 
      0.01 Subscript[x, RandomInteger[{1, i - 1}]][t] /. t -> T;
   {prevSolConds, lastCond} // Flatten];
solveDiffGen[i_] := NDSolve[diffGen[i], vars[i], {t, 0, T}];
```

Comment: Hi @Anjan this idea is exactly what I'm trying to solve. I tried to use your code suggestion, however the following errors appeared and I could not fix them. Do you know what is happening?

Comment: `FindRoot::sszero: The step size in the search has become less than the tolerance prescribed by the PrecisionGoal option, but the function value is still greater than the tolerance prescribed by the AccuracyGoal option. >>`
`NDSolve::berr: There are significant errors {-1.,0.} in the boundary value residuals. Returning the best solution found. >>`

Comment: `FindRoot::sszero: The step size in the search has become less than the tolerance prescribed by the PrecisionGoal option, but the function value is still greater than the tolerance prescribed by the AccuracyGoal option. >>`

`NDSolve::berr: There are significant errors {-1.,0.} in the boundary value residuals. Returning the best solution found. >>`

`FindRoot::sszero: The step size in the search has become less than the tolerance prescribed by the PrecisionGoal option, but the function value is still greater than the tolerance prescribed by the AccuracyGoal option. >>`

Comment: `General::stop: Further output of FindRoot::sszero will be suppressed during this calculation. >>`

`NDSolve::berr: There are significant errors {-1.,0.} in the boundary value residuals. Returning the best solution found. >>`

`General::stop: Further output of NDSolve::berr will be suppressed during this calculation. >>`

Comment: At what value of `i` is it not working?

Comment: I think it is not working well for how the variable `vars` is written

Comment: I guess you can define a vars function for a given `i`

Comment: Check the edit.

Comment: I modified the variable `vars` as your suggestion and the errors persist. I do not know where mistakes might be.